# How to get user details using JWT token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using angular 5 front end and django as back end. I use JWT token to communicate between django to angular. How can I get logged user details in backend using token.

EG:

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = PostDetail
fields = [
'title',
'upvote',
]
```

Here upvote is a many to many field contain all voted user list. I want to add one more field "user_vote_status" to check the vote status of logged in user.

How can I figure out this issue, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. JWT is made of three parts divided by "." The center part contains the user details. So you get that with split and decode that part with window.atob

```
function getUserInfo() {
  const token = getToken();
  let payload;
  if (token) {
    payload = token.split(".")[1];
    payload = window.atob(payload);
    return JSON.parse(payload);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem("jwt-token");
}
```

Comment: A very Valuable information as well as answer. You Solved  my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get usernamec in any django view by this way

```
@api_view(['POST'])    
def apiname(request):
    username = request.user.username
```

as from angular front end, you need to send jwt token in headers

```
Authorization: JWT "token"
```